# Prove that for every set there is a free module on that set

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, free-modules

While studying the book "Module theory: an approach to linear algebra" by T. S. Blyth (the electronic edition of the book is [free to download](https://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10023/12643/ModuleTheory_CCBY.pdf)), I came across a proof that confused me. We need to prove that for every non-empty set $S$ and every unitary ring $R$ there is a free $R$-module on $S$. Here's the complete proof:

[First part of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUfT2.png)
[second part of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEtXp.png)

I couldn't grasp the next to last line, specifically, the following equality:

$$h'(v) = \sum_{s \in S}v(s)h'[f(s)]$$

**Edit:**

It turned out that the source of my confusion was this equality:

$$v =  \sum_{s \in S}v(s)f(s)$$

I thought that $f(s)$ is an element of $R$, when in fact $f(s)$ is a mapping (from $S$ to $R$), and therefore the sum will also be a mapping.

Comment: Just a sidenote: the statement of the theorem is unnecessarily restrictive. The exact same proof works for $S=\emptyset$, too. You get only one map $S\to R$, the empty map, which is the only element of the corresponding free module: the trivial module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is just

$$h^\prime(v) = h^\prime\left(\sum_{s \in S}v(s)[f(s)]\right) = \sum_{s \in S}v(s)h'[f(s)]$$

as $h^\prime$ is supposed to be an $R$-morphism.

Comment: I think I get it now, and you can correct me if I'm wrong. My problem was actually with this equality: $v =  \sum_{s \in S}v(s)f(s)$.

I though that $f(s)$ is an element of $R$, when in fact $f(s)$ is a mapping (from $S$ to $R$), i.e. it's an element of $F$. Therefore, the sum is also a mapping, and for instance, if $S$ was finite, it could be written like this: $map = r_1(map_1) + r_2(map_2) + ... + r_i(map_i)$.

Now, $h'$ is defined on $F$, and since $h'$ is a $R$-morphism, we have $h'(x + y) = h'(x) + h'(y)$, hence $h'(v) = \sum_{s \in S} v(s)h'[f(s)]$.

Comment: You got it! This is it.

Comment: now that I understand it, my question sounds so silly I should delete it, don't you think so?

Comment: Either accept the answer or delete the question. Up to you!

Answer (score 1):

The equality follows from $R$-linearity of the morphism $h'$, and from the previous equation
$$\theta = \sum_{s\in S} \theta(s)f(s)$$
Applying $h'$ to such a sum results in the desired equation.